# pandas fancy indexing and merging back

Tags: python, pandas

What's the simplest way of merging back changes to a pandas dataframe after filtering via fancy indexing?

For example, define a dataframe with two columns x and y, and select all the rows where x is an even integer, and then set the corresponding values in y to 0.

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'x':range(10), 'y':range(11,21)})
d[d.x % 2 == 0]['y'] = 0
```

The "fancy indexing" boolean query makes a copy of the dataframe, so the changes are never propagated back to the original dataframe. Is there a better of performing this operation?

My current solution is to define a temporary dataframe w, based on the fancy boolean indexing, set the corresponding values in 'y' to 0 in w, and then merge w back to d using the index. There must be a more efficient (and hopefully more direct) way of doing this:

```
w = d[d.x % 2 == 0]
w.y = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use DataFrame.ix[]:

```
In [21]: d
Out[21]: 
   x   y
0  0  11
1  1  12
2  2  13

In [22]: d.ix[d.x % 2 == 0, 'y'] = -5

In [23]: d
Out[23]: 
   x   y
0  0  -5
1  1  12
2  2  -5
```